# XSLT sequentially retrieving attribute value from XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I 've got a problem with formatting XML file using XSLT to make HTML. Generally I want to retrieve sequentially values of each attributes contained in XML element.
Currentlz it is hardcoded in XSLT and I realise that if my XML file will change, XSLT won't do its job.
I tried to use something like `<xsl:value-of select="@(name(@*[1]))" />` to retrieve first attribute value of element, but it doesn't work.

How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Here is how it looks like at the moment:

```
<xsl:for-each select="testsuites/testsuite/testcase">
     <xsl:if test="@failure='PASSED'">
         <tr style="color:green;font-weight:bold">
             <td style="text-align:center">
                 <xsl:value-of select="@classname" />
             </td>
             <td style="text-align:center">
                 <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
             </td>
             <td style="text-align:center">
                 <xsl:value-of select="@Plate" />
             </td>
             <td style="text-align:center">
                 <xsl:value-of select="@Distance" />
             </td>
             <td style="text-align:center">
                 <xsl:value-of select="@Side" />
             </td>
             <td style="text-align:center">
                 <xsl:value-of select="@Angle" />
             </td>
             <td style="text-align:center">
                 <xsl:value-of select="@failure" />
             </td>
             <td style="text-align:center">
                 <xsl:value-of select="failure/@message" />
             </td>
         </tr>
     </xsl:if>
     ... and so one
```

Here is a part of my XML file:

```
<testsuites disabled="0" errors="0" failures="1" passes="16" skipped="0"      tests="17" time="1">
    <testsuite disabled="0" id="0" name="Bok" time="1" tests="4">
        <testcase classname="XYZ" name="description" Plate="blah" Distance="A" Side="L" Angle="15" failure="PASSED">
             <system-out/>
             <system-err/>
        </testcase>
        <testcase classname="XYZ" name="description" Plate="blah" Distance="A" Side="L" Angle="60" failure="PASSED">
             <system-out/>
             <system-err/>
        </testcase>
        <testcase classname="XYZ" name="description" Plate="blah" Distance="A" Side="L" Angle="30" failure="PASSED">
             <system-out/>
             <system-err/>
        </testcase>
        <testcase classname="XYZ" name="description" Plate="blah" Distance="A" Side="L" Angle="60" failure="PASSED">
             <system-out/>
             <system-err/>
        </testcase>
    </testsuite>
    ... and so one
```

EDIT:
Ok, as @TimC answered I don't need brackets and name in  `@(name(@*[1]))` and it's fine for me.

Now the problem is how to make a loop which will be iterating elements from 1 to let's say 7, I mean something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$var=1 to 7">
    <td style="text-align:center">
        <xsl:value-of select="@*[$var]" />
    </td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: In your sample failure is not the first attribute, actually there is no failure but failures.

Comment: @derloopkat Attributes are unordered anyway, their order in the source code means nothing.

Comment: well, you said you want first attribute value

Comment: I don't want anything, I'm not the OP. Define "first attribute".

Comment: sorry, my first question was addressed to OP

Comment: I want to get value for example from attribute "classname", so instead of `<xsl:value-of select="@classname" />` I tried this with `<xsl:value-of select="@(name(@*[1]))" />` and in my case it should work in loop to get values of all attributes of element "testsuites/testsuite/testcase".
I want to not write by hand all attributes value but use somehow a loop to retrieve it automatically.

Comment: You can certainly write `<xsl:value-of select="@*[1]" />` but there is no guarantee that will be the classname attribute.

Comment: @TimC +1, now how to make a proper loop for that ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I 've got a problem with formatting XML file using XSLT to make HTML.
>   Generally I want to retrieve sequentially values of each attributes
>   contained in XML element. Currentlz it is hardcoded in XSLT and I
>   realise that if my XML file will change, XSLT won't do its job.

And is a change to the format of the input XML really something that you need to worry about and account for now?  Do think about it.  In any case, whether the existing transform would do its job correctly in the fact of a change to the input XML format depends on what the transform's job is supposed to be, and what manner of change occurs.

If its job is to present a particular set of fields, in a particular order, then it looks to me like it will do its job admirably.  In particular, it will present the selected fields in a consistent order, regardless of the order in which they appear in the input document, emitting empty cells for attributes that are not actually present.  If the output is intended for human consumption, then all that is probably a *good* thing.

> I
>   tried to use something like 
>   to retrieve first attribute value of element, but it doesn't work.
>
> Ok, as @TimC answered I don't need brackets and name in @(name(@*[1]))
>   and it's fine for me.
>
> Now the problem is how to make a loop which will be iterating elements
>   from 1 to let's say 7

No.  If you really want to do this then stop thinking like a procedural programmer.  XSLT does not have loops, *per se*.  Its operational mode involves selecting one or more nodes and then using each in turn as the context for instantiating a template.  Absent any sort directives, it will process nodes in document order.  You're trying to make it much harder than it needs to be.

For example, if you want to process all the attributes of each <testcase> context node, then all you need is something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="@*">
    <td style="text-align:center">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If you want to process only the first 7, regardless of how many there are, then specify it in the selection:

```
<xsl:for-each select="@*[position() < 8]">
    <td style="text-align:center">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If, on the other hand, you want to ensure that you emit exactly 7 <td> elements for each testcase, whether there are that many attributes or not, then either you are back to something along the lines of your original XSL:

```
<td style="text-align:center">
  <xsl:value-of select="@*[1]" />
</td>
<td style="text-align:center">
  <xsl:value-of select="@*[2]" />
</td>
<!-- ... -->
```

or else you need to write a template to perform the iteration, maybe something like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="iterate-testcase-attributes">
  <xsl:with-param name="up-to" select="7"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

...

```
<xsl:template name="iterate-testcase-attributes">
  <xsl:param name="current" select="1"/>
  <xsl:param name="up-to"   select="1"/><!-- the select value is only a default -->
  <td style="text-align:center">
    <!-- will produce nothing if the context node has no such attribute -->
    <xsl:value-of select="@*[position() = $current]" />
  </td>
  <xsl:if test="$current < $up-to">
    <xsl:call-template name="iterate-testcase-attributes">
      <xsl:with-param name="current" select="$current + 1"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="up-to" select="$up-to"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your advices, I have to look at them closely, generally I'm not very familiar with XSLT coding so that's why I ask the question ;)

Comment: My intention was to create an XSLT which would not need many changes after somebody add less or more new attributes to XML.
Anyway thank you for your help again.

Comment: @asdator1213, I think you need to be clarify, at least for yourself, what output you want to produce in the event that (1) one of the attributes you currently expect is not provided, or (2) an additional attribute is provided, or (3) the attributes are presented in a different order than you're used to seeing.  Without that, you have no way to evaluate candidate stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, attributes in XML are un-ordered. If you want want to get all attributes regardless of the order, you could do this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="@*">
  <td style="text-align:center">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But, with multiple `testcase` elements, there is no guarantee the attributes in each row will be in the same order. But if you really wanted to make your XSLT as generic as possible, you could base the order on the first row.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1">
      <xsl:variable name="attrs" select="testsuites/testsuite[1]/testcase[1]/@*" />
      <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="$attrs">
          <th>
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
          </th>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="testsuites/testsuite/testcase[@failure='PASSED']">
        <xsl:variable name="currentCase" select="." />      
        <tr style="color:green;font-weight:bold">
          <xsl:for-each select="$attrs">
           <xsl:variable name="currentAttr" select="local-name()" />      
            <td style="text-align:center">
              <xsl:value-of select="$currentCase/@*[local-name() = $currentAttr]" />
            </td>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ;)